# Bootstrap: How to make the Navbar of the Cover Template responsive (hamburger menu)?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

As part of learning Web Development (#beginner) , I'm currently building a website that takes as a base the official Cover template: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/cover/ .

I really like the design of the demo but I am not able to make the Navbar responsive without modifying the Navbar design.

I checked the documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors) but after various attempts it always get rid of the template design.

My goal is to create a responsive Navbar (hamburger menu) without losing the design of the template.

Could someone help a Web Development student with this issue?

Extract of my html and css files:

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(90deg,#0548f3 10%,#671ef4 110%);   
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.cover-container {
  max-width: 44em;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}

/* Styling curated list page */

.page-list{
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

/*
 * Cover
 */
.cover {
  padding: 30 1.5rem;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.headline {
  font-family: "Inter";
}

/* Cards styling */

.tools-cards {
  background-color: #262626 ;
}

.btn-primary{
background-color: #0335ff;
border-color: #001be6 ;

}

.card-boxing{
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  
}

.card {
  border-radius: 12px;
  
}

.card-badge {
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:-10px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#00d57c;
  color:white;
  border-radius: 12px;

}

.card-badge-paid {
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:-10px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#f3b005;
  color:white;
  border-radius: 12px;

}

/*
 * Footer
 */
.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cover.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</title>
</head>
<body class="text-center">

    <div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
      
      <header class="masthead ">
        <div class="inner">
  
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">Lorem ipsum </h3>
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page Number 1</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <main role="main" class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h1>
        <hr>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary ">Lorem ipsum </a>
        </p>
      </main>

      <footer class="mastfoot mt-auto">
        <div class="inner">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Best,

Matt

Comment: did you fixed the issue?